# XPages: Unite views from 'X' databases in one page

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I am facing the following challenge in an XPage: There are three databases with exactly the same views in it. The goal is to unite these three views from the three databases in one XPage and **one** view component!

AFAIK, one can usually provide just one view per view component. Currently, I have a Java back end where the documents are fetched. They are then processed to HTML markup and made more beautiful / functional by using jQuery data tables.

I see (at least) three disadvantages:

1. It is quite some code and if you want to display another view from the databases you quickly run into boiler plate code...
2. It is not too fast as it takes up to 30 sec. to fetch and display all records.
3. I can hardly image that my way is best practice.

Has anyone ever faced this challenge? I would like to reduce Java code, make it faster and use some standard component if possible.

Comment: It would help to know a bit more: how many total view entries? How often does the data change? And, most importantly, joining data from multiple views is a *technical approach*... what's the *business requirement*?

Comment: Must they be in 1 "view"?  I guess I don't get why they're in 3 db's but you want to eliminate that grouping and place in one view.  Certainly it would be easy to do 3 view controls in a tab control. 1 tab per view or something like that.
Just seems odd to store on the backend seperately but try and show in the UI all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Tim has good questions in his comment. With your current approach make sure you use ViewNavigator cache which is the fastest way to retrieve view entries:

> 1. Notes/Domino Release 8.52 or greater
> 2. View.setAutoUpdate must be False
> 3. ViewNavigator cache must be enabled
> 4. ViewNavigator.getNext() (or getPrev) must be used

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Fast_Retrieval_of_View_Data_Using_the_ViewNavigator_Cache